# Using optional tracking variable in python function

Tags: python

I have a module which I want to use in a couple of different applications. The module is pretty straightforward and has functions which perform a certain task:

```
# Fancy module

# Task1
def do_task1(param1):
  step1()
  step2()
  step3()
```

The first application uses this directly as is.

For the second application, I want to pass a tracker object which keeps track of the status of processing. Something like:

```
# Fancy module with tracker

# Task1
def do_task1(param1, tracker):
  tracker.message = 'Starting step1'
  step1()

  tracker.message = 'Starting step2'
  step2()

  tracker.message = 'Starting step3'
  step3()

  tracker.message = 'Processing completed'
```

I don't want to have 2 versions of the same module library (with and without tracking). One way I can think of to achieve this is to make the tracker optional and then use `if` to track if needed.

```
# Fancy module with conditional tracker

# Task1
def do_task1(param1, tracker=None):
  if tracker:
    tracker.message = 'Starting step1'
  step1()

  if tracker:
    tracker.message = 'Starting step2'
  step2()

  if tracker:
    tracker.message = 'Starting step3'
  step3()

  if tracker:
    tracker.message = 'Processing completed'
```

I'm not too happy with this way of doing it because

- It adds a lot of additional conditions and code (which affects readability)
- There has to be a better way!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to use a dummy tracker as default:

```
class DummyTracker(object):
    # your tracker API implemented here as noop


def do_task1(param1, tracker=None):
    if tracker is None:
        tracker = DummyTracker()
    tracker.message = 'Starting step1'
    step1()

    tracker.message = 'Starting step2'
    step2()

    tracker.message = 'Starting step3'
    step3()

    tracker.message = 'Processing completed'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what my colleague suggested as well. Something on the lines of `if tracker is None: tracker = Tracker()`. Would you be so kind as to just add this piece of code to clarify your answer and I'm happy to mark it as the answer?

Comment: @PlastyGrove done. FWIW we have this very exact pattern in our flagship project

Comment: Nice, thanks! It's a really good idea to just create a dummy rather than import the actual tracker object and use that to instantiate, very helpful :)

Comment: Well the point of the dummy was that in our case the real tracking is done thru redis so better to avoid the overhead when not needed. It might or not make sense in your own project...

Comment: Now that I think about it, I suppose I can also just do `if tracker is None: tracker = {}` since this is python?

Comment: Wont work - `dict` is a slot-based class and does not support arbitrary attribute assignment.

Comment: Yea my bad sorry. I can still use `class DummyTracker(object): pass` right? Then I can assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Tracker` class:

```
Class Tracker(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, tracker=None):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.tracker = tracker

    def do_task1(param1, tracker):
      self.message('Starting step1')
      step1()

      self.message('Starting step2')
      step2()

      self.message('Starting step3')
      step3()

      self.message('Processing completed')

    def message(self, message):
        if self.tracker:
            self.tracker.message = message

tracker_1 = Tracker(3)
tracker_2 = Tracker(3, my_tracker)
```

Comment: This mixes responsabilities and makes the whole very inflexible. Bad design really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alexander. But the `tracker` object is not a part of the same module, so I can't use this.

Comment: @PlastyGrove You should still be able to import it from the other module.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass tracker down and use it inside any one of the functions to log:

```
def do_task1(param1, tracker):
  step1(tracker)
  step2(tracker)
  step3(tracker)
```

where:

```
def step1(tracker=None):
    if tracker:
        tracker.message = 'Starting step1'
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks alfasin, but it still needs the `if` conditions. I think Bruno's answer addresses the issue in the most elegant way.

Comment: @PlastyGrove these answers are orthogonals: you can combine them and get the best of both ;)